# How to randomly select x number of indices from a matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, random, indices

I'm trying to generate a randomly scattered but limited number of 1's in a matrix of zeros efficiently.

Say I have a 10x10 matrix of zeros (`zeros(10)`) and I want to randomly place ten 1's so it looks like:

```
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

How can I do this WITHOUT a for-loop and without manually plugging in each position (this example is a much smaller version of my real problem)?

My code so far:

```
% Generate zeros
M = zeros(10)
% Generate random indices
Rands = [randsample(10, 10) randsample(10, 10)]
```

Where the first column is intended to be the row indices and the second column the column indices.

Now I obviously can't just drop these indices into the row and column indices of `M` like this:

`M(Rands(:,1), Rands(:,2)) = 1`

How can I vecorise the changes to these random indices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`randperm`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html) to randomly generate the linear indices to be filled with `1`:

```
sz = [10 10]; % desired size
n = 10; % desired number of ones
M = zeros(sz);
M(randperm(prod(sz), n)) = 1;
```

Alternatively, you can use `randperm` and [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) in one line:

```
M = reshape(randperm(prod(sz))<=n, sz);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`sub2ind`](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) to convert subscripts to linear index:

```
M(sub2ind(size(M),Rands(:,1),Rands(:,2)))=1
```